# "At least as much as skilled as"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, comparatives

Is this sentence right?

> Xs need to be at least as much as skilled as Ys.

If not what should it be?

Answer (score 9):

> Xs need to be at least as skilled as Ys.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not right. You can say:

> Xs need at least as much skill as Ys.

or

> Xs need to be at least as skilled as Ys.